# Event when enters app and exits from app on KaiOS

Tags: kaios

I need to do some actions when app is launched and exited on KaiOS. Do we have access to the event?

Tried window load unload event, seems not triggered. Tried also react component did mount life cycle method also does not trigger on those events.

Answer (score 0):

Just got it, they apparently trigger window focus and blur event respectively.